# ¿Cómo añadir una miniatura animada de un video en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, iframe

Estoy creando una página web en Wordpress donde los post van a contener un video incrustado dentro de un iframe. Estos videos los cogeré de otros sitios como youtube o vimeo (por ejemplo).
Me gustaría que en la página principal mostrara una lista con todos los post que se van añadiendo, y por cada post se mostrara una miniatura con una especie de gif animado sobre el video(como hace youtube, o un sinfín de página que seguramente todos conocemos).
He probado con plugins, pero no encuentro nada que funcione, ¿Existe alguna manera de hacer esto?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es un gif animado, se me ocurre que puedes agregar ese gif animado como "imagen destacada". Algo rudimentario pero funciona.

Yo lo he probado y sirve, tan sólo el trabajo que te tome crear gifs animados sobre videos.

Pero por la parte de Wordpress, tan sólo agrega el gif a imagen destacada de cada post.

Y después configurar la página principal como una página de entradas.